# Filter items by data type in ng-repeat in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to filter a collection of items by data type (not by value) using the ng-repeat directive in Angular.js?

I have a custom data type via a constructor called BookCollection. Each property is a Book object accessible by an ID. The BookCollection has some additional 'private' properties though that I don't want to iterate over in ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(id, book) in library.books">
```

Comment: Yes... are you actually adding different types of data to an array?  `arr.push(1); arr.push('hello'); arr.push({ obj: true });`?

Comment: I have a custom data type via a constructor called BookCollection. Each property is a Book object accessible by an ID. The BookCollection has some additional 'private' properties though that I don't want to iterate over in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can filter using filter directive. you can provide a call back or you can use string for filter. [see this link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

```
ng-repeat="item in items|filter:'filterstring'"
```

Comment: They allow some more complex filter mechanisms too!